# Createquery, leftjoin and innerjoin in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, inner-join

I’m empty for new ideas – I’m close to throwing in the towel. Doctrine just doesn’t want to play with me..

My program is build up against a MySQL and php webinterface and based on www.qdpm.com. At the moment, I’m having a public function to execute a export of elements in my table “Tasks” to a csv file. So far so good. But my goal is also to export comments from table “Tasks_comments” related from table “Tasks”,  and the user who created the comment from table “Users”.
This can easily be done by a SQL query:

```
SELECT `tasks`.`description`, `tasks_comments`.`description`, `users`.`name`
FROM tasks, tasks_comments
INNER JOIN users on `tasks_comments`.`created_by` = `users`.`id`
```

The hard part is getting this into doctrine – and make it work. I’ve been searching the first 200 pages on Google, and failed approximately the same amount of times.. if not more.

I’m having an action.class.php module which includes my public function executeExport (full code: http://pastebin.com/uWqfd4WC) and a components.class.php (full code: http://pastebin.com/NAJRvaBp).

Public function executeExport:

```
public function executeExport(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    /*check access*/
    if($request->hasParameter('projects_id'))
    {
      $this->forward404Unless($this->projects = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Projects')->createQuery()->addWhere('id=?',$request->getParameter('projects_id'))->fetchOne(), sprintf('Object projects does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('projects_id')));

      $this->checkProjectsAccess($this->projects);
      $this->checkTasksAccess('view',false,$this->projects);
    }
    else
    {
      $this->checkTasksAccess('view');
    }

    /*Form with checklist on what I want to export*/  
    $this->columns = array(
                           'Projects'       => t::__('Project Name'),
                           'id'             => t::__('Id'),
                           'TasksGroups'    => t::__('Group'),
                           'Versions'        => t::__('Version'),
                           'ProjectsPhases' => t::__('Phase'),                 
                           'TasksPriority'  => t::__('Priority'),
                           'TasksLabels'     => t::__('Label'),                                  
                           'name'     => t::__('Name'),
                           'TasksStatus'    => t::__('Status'),
                           'TasksTypes'      => t::__('Type'),                 
                           'assigned_to'    => t::__('Assigned To'),
                           'Users'     => t::__('Created By'),
                           'estimated_time' => t::__('Est. Time'),
                           'work_hours'     => t::__('Work Hours'),                                                      
                           'start_date'     => t::__('Start Date'),
                           'due_date'       => t::__('Due Date'),
                           'progress'       => t::__('Progress'),
                           'created_at'     => t::__('Created At'),
                           'description'    => t::__('Description'),

                          );

    $extra_fields = ExtraFieldsList::getFieldsByType('tasks',$this->getUser(),false,array('all'=>true));

    foreach($extra_fields as $v)
    {
      $this->columns['extra_field_' . $v['id']]=$v['name'];
    }   




    $this->columns['url']=t::__('Url');

    if($fields = $request->getParameter('fields'))
    {
      $separator = "\t";
      $format = $request->getParameter('format','.csv');
      $filename = $request->getParameter('filename','tasks');

            header("Content-type: Application/octet-stream");      
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . "." . $format);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");

      $content = '';
      foreach($fields as $f)
      {
        $content .= str_replace(array("\n\r","\r","\n",$separator),' ',$this->columns[$f]) . $separator;
      }
      $content .= "\n";

      if($format=='csv')
      {
        echo chr( 0xFF ) . chr( 0xFE ) . mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8' );
      }
      else
      {
        echo $content;
      }

      if(strlen($request->getParameter('selected_items')==0)) exit();

/*Query at the time*/      
$q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tasks')->createQuery('t')
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksPriority tp')
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksStatus ts')
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksLabels tl')
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksTypes tt')
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksGroups tg')
          ->leftJoin('t.ProjectsPhases pp')
          ->leftJoin('t.Versions v')
          ->leftJoin('t.Projects p')
          ->leftJoin('t.Users')  
          ->leftJoin('t.TasksComments')                            
          ->whereIn('t.id',explode(',',$request->getParameter('selected_items')));
```

Schema.yml:

```
Tasks:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: tasks
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    projects_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_status_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_priority_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_type_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_label_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_groups_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    projects_phases_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    versions_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_by:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    assigned_to:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    estimated_time:
      type: float()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    due_date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tickets_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    closed_date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    discussion_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    start_date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    progress:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Projects:
      local: projects_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Tickets:
      local: tickets_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksStatus:
      local: tasks_status_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksPriority:
      local: tasks_priority_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksTypes:
      local: tasks_type_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksLabels:
      local: tasks_label_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksGroups:
      local: tasks_groups_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    ProjectsPhases:
      local: projects_phases_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Versions:
      local: versions_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Users:
      local: created_by
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksComments:
      local: id
      foreign: tasks_id
      type: many
TasksComments:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: tasks_comments
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    tasks_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    created_by:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_status_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tasks_priority_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    due_date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    worked_hours:
      type: float()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    progress:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Tasks:
      local: tasks_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Users:
      local: created_by
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksStatus:
      local: tasks_status_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    TasksPriority:
      local: tasks_priority_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

The three tables which I want to use is:

1. Tasks (picture from phpadmin:
   s2.postimg.org/3sf75m055/web16_meebox_net_db16_meebox_net_commissi_qd.png)
2. Tasks_comments (picture from phpadmin:
   s11.postimg.org/lfrtdnw9v/web16_meebox_net_db16_meebox_net_commissi_qd.png)
3. Users

Is this maybe possible with a sub query? Or do YOU have the magic line of code I need to add? Just got an idea, I'm game!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it in another way.

1. Found the connection file in the programs config file.
2. Created php file with the connection options
3. Created php file with combobox with a query which got project names
4. Created php fOkay, I solved it in another way.
5. Found the connection file in the programs config file.
6. Created php file with the connection options
7. Created php file with combobox with a query which got project names
8. Created php file which exported a query to csv with a where statement from the comboboxile which exported a query to csv with a where statement from the combobox